# Check failed: 1 == NumElements() (1 vs. 2)Must have a one element tensor (Neural network metric)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

I have my Neural network int TF2 and for that I want to make my own metric. In my function I iterate throw each tensor value and canlculate new value into output_list. That I will stack as my new y_pred and throw it into mean_absolute_error. Compilaction is OK, but in first iteration I get error in the title. What am I doing wrong?

```
@tf.function 
def custom_metric_mae( y_true , y_pred ):
    output_list=tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=tf.shape(y_pred))
    for i in range(223):
        dphi = abs(y_true[i][0]-y_pred[i][0])
        if(dphi > 0.5):
            output_list.write(i,1 - dphi)
        else:
            output_list.write(i,dphi)     
    y_PredChanged = output_list.stack()
    return tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_true , y_PredChanged)
```

My model:

```
    model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32,32)),
    keras.layers.Dense(64,activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(32,activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(16,activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
    ])
model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss = "mean_absolute_error",metrics=[custom_metric_mae])
```

Comment: Can you share your error?

Comment: it happens on first epoch of training:
Train on 223 samples
Epoch 1/1000
2020-2-06 15:44:57.610700: F tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.cc:644] Check failed: 1 == NumElements() (1 vs. 2)Must have one element tensor

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [Keras' custom metrics](https://keras.io/metrics/#custom-metrics):

> The function would need to take (y_true, y_pred) as arguments and return a single tensor value.

[`tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/metrics/mean_absolute_error) returns **two** values: the actual MAE and an `update_op` that, once evaluated, updates the running values and returns the MAE value. I'm not entirely sure whether this is compatible with Keras, I'd suggest to replace it with `keras.metrics.mae` instead.

Do note that when using Keras's `mae`, you need to average the final result (the function is applied to the last dimension of `y_true` and `y_pred` and the result has shape `y_true.shape[:-1]` which, in general, won't be one value). To do so, use `tf.math.reduce_mean`:

```
return tf.math.reduce_mean(keras.metrics.mae(y_true , y_PredChanged))
```

Comment: I changed it to keras.metrics.mae. Still same error during first epoch.

Comment: Still same error during first epoch, but thank you for your suggestions.